# MVC Sharing strongly typed Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to render a strongly typed partial view and share it between different parent views.

so I would have a parent view A that is an edit form which has element as well as partial view for Location.

```
@model Model.Contact
....                
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LocationID)
@{Html.RenderPartial("../Shared/_Location", Model.Location);}
```

partial view is an edit form update/insert form

```
@model Model.Location
....with form elements bound to model passed
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        Address 1<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1)<br />
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        Address 2<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address2)<br />
    </div>
</div>......
```

and view B is bounded to different model which also has a need to update Location.

```
@model Model.JobAssignment
....                
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OriginLocationID)
@{Html.RenderPartial("../Shared/_Location", Model.OriginLocation);}
```

It's OriginLocation because this entity has multiple FKs to Location thus I named them differently in CodeFirstMapping

```
    [ForeignKey("OriginLocationID")]
    public virtual Location OriginLocation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DestinationLocationID")]
    public virtual Location DestinationLocation { get; set; }
```

Database and and Entities are all fine with Fk properly setup to Location by Job and Contact.

What i had before is Location partial view would not get a location entity/model but instead be bound to whatever parent model is like  @model Model.Contact just like parent view, that would work fine, as the controls in partial view is prefixed with Location.* and Location_* for ID and it works its magic, having controls as: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location.Address1)

but im trying to share the location partial view just like I used to do with UserControls in asp.net, so want to bind it to

I cannot get it to work, the closest I get is to bound the data, but on edit/save I get strange error.

***"A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion."***

Please Please somebody point me to the right direction!